# UICollectionView and Number of Cells on Each Column

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

As show in the screenshot below, I have a UICollectionView with a number of cells.  Currently, device's orientation is Portrait.

[image]

Since I have the following code, there are as many as 19 cells on each column.

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section;
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 100, 0, 100);
}
```

If I change the orientation to Landscape, the number of cells on each column will change.  Is it possible to have the same number of columns regardless of device's orientation?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: on changing the orientation the parent size decreases causing no of columns to get decreased to auto fit in screen. May be you can find any method in documentation to increase the row instead and keep the no of cell fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches that you could take. You could just add a width constraint to your collection view in IB (and make sure that you only have a single constraint to the sides or have a single centering constraint in the width direction).

Another approach would be to change the insets based on the orientation. You would override didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: and inspect the interfaceOrientation property to determine which orientation you're in, and then set the insets appropriately.

Comment: Thanks.  I've already tried the latter.  It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @TBlue, it should -- you should post the code you tried, and indicate what results you got.

Comment: I now understand why setting the insets doesn't properly work.  You must reload cells after resetting the insets for each orientation.